# Drools score calculation with nested classes fails for derived class

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

My context is a Java Optaplanner application that uses Drools for score calculation (similar to the optaplanner examples).

After splitting some classes in base classes and derived classes I get an error in the score calculation:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are errors in a score DRL:
Error Messages:
Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=de/.../Rules.drl, line=77, column=0
   text=Unable to Analyse Expression var.type.prop2:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: de...PropType.prop2]
```

Access to the nested variables works fine in the main Java code.

The problem is related to the access to nested variables in the Drools rules, when the 2nd level (`class1.class2.param`) is a derived class. I try to describe this in a small example extracted from my more complicated code (I tried to keep it small, if a complete minimal example would be better I can try to extend it):

The planning entity:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class PlanningE{
    // ...

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"something"})
    private SomePlanningVar var;
}
```

This will be the planning variable:

```
public class SomePlanningVar{
    private PropType type;

    //getter, setter, constructor 
    }
}
```

And finally the classes used in the planning variable, holding some values. (Note that `PropTypeB` extends `PropType`):

```
public class PropType{
    private Integer prop1;

    //getter, setter, constructor 
}

public class PropTypeB extends PropType{
    private Integer prop2;

    // getter setter constructor
}
```

Setup pseudo code

```
...
PropTypeB prop = new PropTypeB(...)
SomePlanningVar pvar = new SomePlanningVar(prop)
...
```

The drools rule in question is:

```
rule "prop"
    when
        PlanningE($value : var.type.prop2)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$value);
end
```

This rule will work fine when I do not split `PropType` in a base and derived class (and just add `prop2` to `PropType`), but it seems to me that this kind of inheritance might be quite common.

Drools seems to somehow not see the correct signature for the derived class, although in the Java code this works without issues.

I suspect I'm getting something wrong with how the inheritance works in Java and/or Drools (having a strong Python background but relatively new to Java), but for now I don't see what.

Anyone any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: PlanningE doesn't have an attribute called proptype. I don't see how you can access prop2 through type, which is of class PropType. - Show us the exact Java code where "this works without issues".

Comment: @laune Yes, you got me. I tried to reduce quite some code to a small example and messed it up. I hope I corrected the mistakes in the example. I'm a bit reluctant to extend this to a full working example as this involves the full optaplanner machinery, but if you think this would help I'll do it.

Comment: Polymorphism is completely supported in Drools and OptaPlanner. For example, OptaPlanner has unit tests with [these classes](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-core/src/test/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/testdata/domain/extended). Similarly, Drools has tests (probably in MiscTest ;). So if there's indeed a bug here, on either project, do create a jira and and submit a pull request with a failing unit to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is quite simple. Seeing the accessor

```
var.type.prop2
```

static analysis (which is the only one a compiler can do) detects that var is of class SomePlanningVar, and its type is of class PropType. This doesn't have a property called prop2 - end of the story.

One of the ways out of the dilemma is to add prop2 to the parent class:

```
public class PropType{
    private Integer prop2;
    public Integer getProp2(){ return prop2; }
}
```

PropTypeB will override the PropType method getProp2. You can throw an exception in PropType.getProp2 if you want to catch erroneous calls.

Also, making PropType and PropType.getProp2 abstract is possible if you never create objects of class PropType.

You may want to review the design of your classes, too. Why do you have PropType in the rules when you expect a PropTypeB? Wouldn't it be preferable to write the rule against the subclass?

Comment: I re-checked, and I don't think this is that simple (although I hoped). "static analysis ... end of the story.": The `SomePlanningVar` class accepts a `PropType` as var - but this includes classes derived from `PropType`, as is `PropTypeB`. This is what I meant with "the java part works fine". I can of course instantiate `SomePlanningVar` with a `PropTypeB` and then access 'var.prop.prop2'. But this does not work in the Drools-part of the prog. I do some tests and try to build a working minimal example, maybe that alone is enough for the issue to resolve.. But many thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Then using an abstract class for PropType is the way to go. The method doesn't need to be abstract if its call for a non-PropTypeB-object can be handled in some way. -- Otherwise I'd have reservations against your class hierarchy.